# how can I generate a random 6 digits number with this rule? BY PHP

Tags: php, random, match, preg-match

I have a function called rndgen() generate random 6 digits number that can have zero digit everywhere even  beginning of number.

example:

267809

671485

200000

037481

000005

000437

500005

777777

**I dont want to generate numbers like 000024 or 240000 or 000005 or 140000 or 500005 or 999999, and there are numbers like 000124 or 245000 or 000555 or 145000 or 511005 or 999887 allowed to generate.**

**All numbers that have the same digits are not allowed**

How can I check this number if more than three digits are the beginning or end of the zero OR more than three zero in the middle of the number, it generate a new number, but if the zeros were at the beginning or end, lower or none could use the same number( BY PHP )?

The Rules I want:

after generating number>

IF (
NUMBER HAS MORE THAN THREE ZERO AT THE BEGINNING OR END OF NUMBER

OR

WHOLE NUMBER HAVE THE SAME DIGITS

OR

NUMBER HAS MORE THAN THREE SAME DIGITS AT THE BEGINNING OR END OF NUMBER

OR

NUMBER HAS MORE THAN THREE ZERO AT IN THE MIDDLE OF NUMBER

)

{ CALL AGAIN rndgen() TO GENERATE NEW RANDOM 6 DIGITS NUMBER }

thanks

Comment: What?? Can you give some examples? The part below the numbers is unclear (for me at least)

Comment: Why 999999? What is the rule that excludes this one? Is 505000 allowed?

Comment: You should post the rules that you need

Comment: If 999999 is not allowed, is 888888 allowed?

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte.    Yes, 505000 is allowed

Comment: What about 188882, 7777733? Could you do an effort to clearly specify the rule?

Comment: Can we understand the rule as follows? Reject any number that has the same digit repeated more than 3 times without interruption. So this would also reject 188882, 777733. But it would allow 616661. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sorry i'm not good at explaining ,  I'm trying to edit it.

Comment: @trincot   this rule is  just for zero digit

Comment: So is this rule for other digits then: "NUMBER HAS MORE THAN THREE SAME DIGITS AT THE BEGINNING OR END OF NUMBER"?

Comment: @trincot "NUMBER HAS MORE THAN THREE SAME DIGITS AT THE BEGINNING OR END OF NUMBER"  is for all digits 0 - 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to reject numbers that have:

- a digit repeating for more than 3 times without interruption at either end of the number, OR:
- a zero repeating for more than 3 times without interruption anywhere in the number.

This you can do with the following regular expression in a `preg_match` function call:

```
^(\d)\1\1\1|(\d)\2\2\2$|0000
```

If that matches, then you have a number that should be rejected.

Here is code to test several numbers:

```
$tests = array(
    "000024", "241111", "222225", "143333", "500005", "999999", 
    "000124", "245111", "222555", "145333", "544445", "799997"
);

foreach($tests as $num) {
    $reject = preg_match("~^(\d)\\1\\1\\1|(\d)\\2\\2\\2$|0000~", $num);
    echo "$num: " . ($reject ? "Not OK" : "OK") . "\n";
}
```

The first 6 will print as "Not OK", the other 6 as "OK".

Your `rndgen` function could use that as follows:

```
function rndgen() {
    do {
        $num = sprintf('%06d', mt_rand(100, 999989));
    } while (preg_match("~^(\d)\\1\\1\\1|(\d)\\2\\2\\2$|0000~", $num));
    return $num;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,its very useful. **how should I edit this code for 4 digit random number???** reject numbers that have: a digit repeating for more than 2 times without interruption at either end of the number, OR: a zero repeating for more than 2 times without interruption anywhere in the number

Comment: I edited in this way: preg_match("~^(\d)\\1\\1|(\d)\\2\\2$|00~", $num);   **Is it correct?**

Answer (score 1):

Using arithmetic:

```
function rndgen() {
    do {
        $n = mt_rand(100, 999899);
    } while ( !($n/100%1111 && $n%1e4%1111 && $n%1e5 > 9) );
    return sprintf("%06d", $n);
}

echo rndgen();
```

**About the number range 100, 999899:** all numbers lower than 100 need to be excluded since they all returns 4 leading zeros: 0000xx, and all numbers greater than 999899 need to be excluded too since they all have 4 leading nine: 9999xx

**About the conditions:**

`$n/100%1111`: shifts the dozens and units to the decimal part and calculates the 1111 modulo. ex:

```
$n                       123456        444412       124444      100002
$n/100                     1234.56       4444.12      1244.44     1000.02
%1111                       123             0          133        1000
```

`$n%1e4%1111`: removes dozens of thousands and calculates the 1111 modulo. ex:

```
$n                       123456        444412       124444      100002
$n%1e4                     3456          4412         4444           2
%1111                       123          1079            0           2
```

`$n%1e5 > 9`: calculates the 100000 modulo and checks if it is greater than 9. ex:

```
$n                       123456        444412       124444      100002
$n%1e5                    23456         44412         4444           2
> 9                        true          true         true       false
```